# Does GLKit limit me to two attributes?

Tags: swift, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-shader, glkit

I've been working with some GLKit code for the past few days that has a color attribute and a position attribute, but when I try to add a normal attribute it crashes every time.

Vertex Shader:

```
 attribute vec4 SourceColor;
 attribute vec4 aVertexPosition;
 attribute vec4 aVertexNormal;

varying vec4 DestinationColor;


uniform mat4 uPMatrix; /* perspectiveView matrix */
uniform mat4 uVMatrix; /* view matrix */
uniform mat4 uOMatrix; /* object matrix */


uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 ModelView;
uniform float u_time;

void main(void) {
     DestinationColor = SourceColor;
     gl_Position = aVertexPosition * Projection;
}
```

Code:

```
    self.colorSlot =    glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "SourceColor")
    self.positionSlot = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "aVertexPosition")
    self.normalSlot =   glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "aVertexNormal")
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLuint(self.positionSlot))
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLuint(self.colorSlot))
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLuint(self.normalSlot))<-crashes here
```

Comment: What does the crash say? None of these are from GLKit btw. What part of the kit are you using? Check if the normalSlot value makes sense or is it some strange value.

Comment: Error Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTIONS and self.normalSlot  = -1

Comment: -1 is invalid. For some reason it didn't get the value from the shader. What do you think the GLuint typecast does with this value? Anyway most likely this is some trivial mistake but the compiled shader seems to be missing that attribute..

Comment: I wonder if the fact you don't use the normalSlot attribute in your shader means the linker ignores it and therefore it's invalid later.

Comment: That is actually quite possible, good observation Steve. Try at least adding a varying normal to both vertex and fragment shader and simply assign the attribute value to it in vertex shader and check if the issue persists. But in general do try to check the values before using them. Typecasting a negative value into unsigned is always dangerous. You can get some very large value and a crash which probably happened to you or even worse it could set a zero value and potentially override some other attribute such as position.. Imagine finding the bug in that situation..

Comment: Turns out unless I actually use attributes instead of just declare them, the code will crash, which I figured out after switching to glBindAttribLocation(), which doesn't have the same requirement

Answer (score 0):

As found through the comments the reason for this crash that the value `self.normalSlot` was `-1` which is returned when `glGetAttribLocation` fails to find the attribute with the specified name. The value `-1` was then typecast using `GLuint(self.normalSlot)` which most likely produced a very large value which is not supported in enabling vertex attribute array causing a crash. So before using a location for attribute and uniform you should check if the location was retrieved. A valid locations are positive values so `location >= 0` should be checked.

Still the attribute was present in the shader source but the location was not retrieved. It seems the reason for that is the attribute was never used in the shader so it might be a compiler optimization. In any case you may not force the attribute by simply declaring it in the vertex shader, you need to also use it. There seems to be another way to force it which is by using `glBindAttribLocation`. I would not expect this to guarantee the existence of the attribute so you should still at least check the GL errors after using it to avoid additional issues.

Note:
If you are using `glBindAttribLocation` make sure you completely understand its documentation. It is very easy to lose track of these indices and you should have a smart system or personal standards on how you index the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely agree with Matik, but the limit for number of attributes really exists. It may be checked by GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS:

```
int max;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS, &max);
NSLog(@"GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS=%@", @(max));
```

I got `GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS=16` for my iPod 5. This is much more than two.